# Is there any way to combine my Reddit karma points?

Tags: reddit

I have two Reddit accounts.  My main one I use every day and struggle to get points.  I did a throw away for a wildly popular post.  I'd love to move the points from the throw away into my normal account.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it seems that this is **impossible**. [From the FAQ](http://www.reddit.com/help/faq#Iwanttochangemyusername.DoIhavetostartanewaccount):

> I want to change my username. Do I
>   have to start a new account?
>
> Yes. Once a user account is created,
>   the username cannot be edited. You can
>   create a new user profile but **cannot
>   migrate karma or comment karma to the
>   new username**.

Just in case, you might want to contact a Reddit moderator. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you that we do this for Stack Overflow users, **if they can prove they own both accounts**.

Here's what I'd ask for, if someone wanted this done on SO (or any SE site):

- editing each account to include something unique that only you would know -- this part is important, to prove ownership.
- email the Reddit moderators with direct easy click URLs to both accounts in your email
- explain the situation, and ask nicely

We always do this for our users, *particularly* if they make it easy for us!